# How do I check a user inputted name?

Tags: python, input

```py
input("Name: ")
if input == "Assafa":
    print("11")
else:
    print("Not found")
```

If I input the name "Assafa" I get this:

```
Name: Assafa
Not found
```

Comment: Assign `input("Name: ")` to a variable. This will hold the input from the user. Then instead of `input  == "Assafa" ` use the `<VARIABLE_NAME>== "Assafa" `

Comment: I have trimmed down your program to a short snippet that still has the same problem as the original program. Try doing this yourself when you're debugging. Removing unrelated pieces of code will help you narrow down where the problem is so you're only looking at 5 lines of code rather than 50. For more information, see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your `input("Name: ")` into a variable.

Example:

```
name = input("Name: ")
if name == "Assafa":
    print("11")
else:
    print("Not found")
```